# ¿Es posible hacer FindOne con datos cifrados usando BSON con Mongodb y Golang?

Tags: mongodb, backend, go

Estoy practicando Go y Mongo para desarrollar Backend, la contraseña la guardo cifrada con BCrypt, la recupero con el email y comparo los hashes del password con el mismo BCrypt, hasta ahí todo bien.

Pero mi intención es guardar el resto de los datos del usuario, incluído el email, como strings cifradas de forma simétrica con algunas funciones de Crypto; sin embargo, no he encontrado información acerca de sí es posible comparar esos datos cifrados directamente en las condiciones del BSON, por ejemplo, comprobar si el email ya está registrado o para recuperar también la contraseña cifrada para posteriormente comparar su hash con BCrypt.

Por ahora solo puedo hacer la consulta mientras el email esté guardado en texto plano:

```
        email := "email@dominio.com"

        users := dbName.Collection("users")
        conditions := bson.M{"email": email}

        var result modelos.User
        users.FindOne(ctx, conditions).Decode (&result)

        if(result != nil){
                fmt.Println("El email ya se ha registrado anteriormente.")
        }
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de como hacer esa condición cuando los valores estén cifrados?

Porque la única forma que he encontrado es, primero recuperar todos los documentos de la colección, luego hacer un fetch, descifrar el email y compararlo, pero si es posible, quisiera ahorrarme esa carga del servidor cada que tenga que comparar algún dato cifrado en una consulta a la BD.

De antemano, gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Si la representación que almacenas en los documentos de MongoDB es de cadena, sólo debes cifrar los datos antes de la consulta. Suponiendo que un email produce una cadena cifrada de la siguiente forma: `"aFdqr9$k1T@_"` entonces al usar `findOne` pasando como argumento: `{ email: "aFdqr9$k1T@_" }` funcionará sin problemas. Ahora si lo que quieres es que MongoDB cifre y descifre automáticamente los datos tanto al escribirlos como al leerlos mucho me temo que [no es una característica gratuita](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu respuesta. Ya intenté hacerlo de esa forma, pero debido a que las funciones para encriptarlos utilizan algunos valores aleatorios para completar la longitud de la clave privada a valores definidos por Crypto (por ejemplo, 16, 24, 32), los hashes siempre serán diferentes por lo que nunca habrá una coincidencia. Tal vez la única forma de hacerlo sin aumentar la carga al servidor en el controller, sea usando la versión de pago de MongoBD. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Quieres cifrar o crear hash a partir de los datos? Son cosas diferentes. El cifrado consiste en ocultar un valor para recuperarlo luego, en cambio el hash es simplemente una representación codificada de un valor. Un mensaje cifrado se puede descifrar, en cambio un hash es prácticamente imposible descifrarlo (depende del algoritmo usado para generar el hash). Exactamente qué necesitas hacer?

Comment: @MauricioContreras, tal vez me expresé mal al referirme cómo hashes a las cadenas cifradas, una disculpa. Me refería a que la cadena cifrada resultante, siempre es diferente debido a los valores aleatorios que se agregan a la clave privada al momento de cifrarlos, por lo que no coincidirá con la cadena cifrada guardada en la BD, aunque el texto original sea el mismo.